# How to pass Json variable as inputs in Azure DevOps pipeline task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am forming a JSON dynamically during the pipeline run based on few pipeline parameters and pre-defined environment variables and trying to pass this JSON as an input in subsequent pipeline task.

```
   jobs:
     - job: PayloadCreation
       pool: linux-agent (or windows)
       steps:
        - ${{ each app in apps }}:
            - bash: |
                payload=$(jq .artifact += [{"name": "${{ app.name}}, "version":"$(Build.BuildId)"}]' artifact.json)
                echo $payload > artifact.json
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=payload]$payload"
```

I am getting the output of `artifact.json` as well as variable $payload as follows -

```
"artifacts": [
  {
    "name":"service-a",
    "version":"1.0.0"
  },
  {
    "name":"service-b",
    "version": "1.0.1"
  }
 ]
}
```

Subsequently, I am trying to use this JSON variable to pass it as input in the following job and unable to do so.

```
 - job: JobB
   steps:
     - task: SericeNow-DevOps-Agent-Artifact-Registration@1
       inputs:
         connectedServiceName: 'test-SC'
         artifactsPayload: $(payload)
```

It is unable to read the JSON as input variable. I get the below error -
`Artifact Registration could not be sent due to the exception: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 0`

Is there any other way a JSON could be passed as input variable?

Comment: Hi, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way a JSON could be passed as input variable?

Strictly, no. Variables under the concept of DevOps pipeline doesn't support JSON object.

Why no?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables

> Variables are always strings.

But this doesn't mean you can't pass the JSON information, if you want, passing string is the only way.

Is the task designed by yourself?

Convert string object to JSON object is not a difficult:

```
//convert string object to json object

var str = `
{
"artifacts": [
    {
      "name":"service-a",
      "version":"1.0.0"
    },
    {
      "name":"service-b",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
   ]
  }
`;
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj.artifacts[0].name);
console.log(obj.artifacts[0].version);
```

Not sure how your task design, but Daniel's method of passing variables is correct.

You can do operations in your extension task code after convert the string object to JSON object.

Here I add other relevant information of the logging command:

[Set Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)

[Variables Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#levels-of-output-variables)

By the way, in your question, the json is

```
"artifacts": [
  {
    "name":"service-a",
    "version":"1.0.0"
  },
  {
    "name":"service-b",
    "version": "1.0.1"
  }
 ]
}
```

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
{
"artifacts": [
  {
    "name":"service-a",
    "version":"1.0.0"
  },
  {
    "name":"service-b",
    "version": "1.0.1"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I see you converted string object to JSON object. However, the JSON is something that’s generated dynamically using jq. So, it would not be possible in my context to define JSON as string variable as defined above.

Answer (score 0):

By default, variables are not available between jobs. In `JobB`, the `$(payload)` variable is not defined.

When setting the variable, you need to provide `isOutput`: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=payload;isOutput=true]$payload"`

When referencing the variable, you need to use the appropriate runtime expression:

```
variables:
  payload: $[ dependencies.PayloadCreation.outputs['payload'] ]
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#share-variables-across-pipelines

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info. I tried the above way of outputting the variable and reading it in next job. I do not think it is able to read the variable that way as it is a JSON and not a string. Should I be reading variable any differently for a JSON.  I am getting an error Input Required: artifactsPayload  - which indicates it is unable to find the value for that.